# Compile error: clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: compile, mac-os-x

After not using Mathematica 10.0.2.0 for a few months (I think since december 2018) on my MacBook Pro from 2013 (now with macOS Mojave 10.14.5) I am suddenly facing issues with `Compile`. I've installed the latest Xcode and agreed to the license terms, but I still get the error:

> > CCompilerDriver`CreateLibrary::cmperr: "Compile error: clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> >
> > Compile::nogen: A library could not be generated from the compiled function.

when I try to do even a trivial

`Compile[{{x, _Real}}, x*x, CompilationTarget -> "C"]`

Any tips on how to debug or a known solution?

**EDIT:**

After doing

```
Compiler`$CCompilerOptions = {"ShellOutputFunction" -> Print};
```

I see the message

> > clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a 
> >     minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9 [-Wdeprecated]
> >
> > ld: library not found for -lstdc++

I'm guessing this last error is (part of) the crux of the matter.

**EDIT 2:**

I tried to change the compiler from clang to gcc but I don't think `Compile` noticed (?): I did

```
$CCompiler = CCompilerDriver`GCCCompiler`GCCCompiler;
DefaultCCompiler[]
```

> > CCompilerDriver`GCCCompiler`GCCCompiler

but when I run the `Compile` line above, I still get clang-related errors...

Comment: If the XCode installation is younger than _Mathematica's_ then _Mathematica_ might have a problem with detecting it correctly. Have you tried to kust reinstall _Mathematica_?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, I'm hesitating to do that because I'll only be using this MMA licence for maybe 5 more weeks (as you know, 10.0.2.0 is old...). I have a feeling this might have to do with macOS' switch from libstdc++ to libc++. Do you know how I can tell MMA to use libc++?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, no worries, thanks for reading my post :) Here's hoping Szabolcs will see the post, I have a hunch he has been dealing with this :P

Comment: Best way to make sure that he reads it: @Szabolcs!   ;)

Comment: This is due to Apple removing libstdc++. You may need to change `CCompilerDriver\`ClangCompiler\`Private\`dllLinkLibs["MacOSX-x86-64"]` to use `-lc++` instead of `-lstdc++`

Comment: @ilian thanks a bunch, that was it!! Any way to make this change permanent for this machine and _Mathematica_ installation?

Comment: Could be done in init.m I think, just load CCompilerDriver first

Comment: @ilian thanks again, do you mind posting an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the comments into an answer:

As of version 10.4.0, CCompilerDriver will link to libc++ on Mac by default.

Earlier versions, however, link to libstdc++ and will run into this problem, because that library is no longer available (Apple deprecated it in Xcode 8 and finally removed it in Xcode 10).

The issue can be worked around by setting the following variables, used when linking executables and dynamic libraries respectively

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]

CCompilerDriver`ClangCompiler`Private`dllLinkLibs["MacOSX-x86-64"] = "-lc++";
CCompilerDriver`ClangCompiler`Private`exeLinkLibraries["MacOSX-x86-64"] = "-lm -lpthread -lc++";
```

It may be convenient to place the above code in the kernel's `init.m` file so compilation works in every session.